PHPMailer only sends emails if there is a CC field
I want to make it so that the CC field is optional to have, but right now, the email only sends if there is a cc field, and if I don't have a $CC value, it throws an error "Invalid address: cc"
$mail->addAddress($EmailTo);
$mail->addCC($CC);
$mail->Subject = $Subject;
$mail->Body    = nl2br($Message);
$mail->AltBody = nl2br($Message);
$mail->isHTML(false); 
$mail->send();

The email also sends if I remove any lines with $CC to just the one email, but I also tried to add this since I thought it's throwing an error because the CC field was empty
if (isset($_POST['emailfrom'])) {
$mail->addCC($CC);
} else {
$mail->send();
}


" I thought it's throwing an error"  is it throwing an error? What error is it throwing? Edit the complete text into your question.

CC has always been optional, there's no reason why you should need to add it. Can you check your mail logs to see if the message is actually being sent? I suspect the problem is not in PHP, maybe some spam filter is sensitive to this.

the message is sent when I have both fields (CC and emailto) set when i have addCC, and it doesn't work if CC is not set. If I remove it, I can send one email to whatevers in emailto, but obviously the cc field wont work.

What does the phpmailer debug mode say about what is happening to the email? Because this really doesn't make sense, to be honest

it just says "Invalid address: (cc):". It's supposed to be empty though, and I though addCC skips over invalid addresses?

OK. So what does $CC contain when you run the code,? We can't see how it's populated or what value it has

I completely misunderstood the question. I thought you meant that it only sends if you call addCC(), not only if $CC is filled. It never occurred to me that you would call it with an invalid address.

Be aware that both addAddress and addCC will return an error code if you provide an invalid address, so maybe add some error checking? Separately, there’s no good reason to use nl2br on AltBody; you don’t want HTML tags in your plain text.

solution: replaced $mail->addCC($CC); with
if (!empty($CC)) {
$mail->addCC($CC);
}


First line can be follows:
$mail->addAddress( 'main_mail@gmail.com', 'Mr. Main' );
Ur email direction must exists.
$toEmail = $value['email']; // 'testing@gmail.com'
$toName = $value['name']; // 'Mr. Testing'
$mail->addCC($toEmail, $toName);
